# Проблема с MAP в Java

Tags: java, коллекции

Вот у меня есть два java-файла. в одном написано:

```
    public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Adult player = new Adult();
        player.addPlayer("Mick");
        player.addPlayer("Alice");
        player.players.values();
    }
}
```

в другом:

```
  public class Adult {
        protected Map<Integer, String> players = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        test test;
        int id;
        public void addPlayer (String name) {
            players.put(newId(id),name);
        }

    public int newId (int oldId) {
        this.id = oldId + 1;
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

В итоге я ожидал получить два строчки:

> 1, Mick
> 2, Alice

Но компилятор отмолчался. Даже ошибку никакую не выдал. Подскажите в чём "косяк", пожалуйста.

Comment: Слишком много слов player на квадратный сантиметр кода

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что проблема вызвана опечаткой и решение вряд ли будет полезным другим участникам.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

facepalm.jpg

Вы *не выводите* эти значения. Вы просто вызываете метод `player.players.values();`, который возвращает значения, хранящиеся в Map, но вы их не выводите на консоль (или куда-нибудь ещё) и даже не присваиваете их какой-нибудь переменной. Если вы ожидаете, что они выведутся в консоль, то правильно будет так:

```
System.out.println(player.players.values());
```